# How can I pass the $(this) to a function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='pos_']").change(UpdatePosition)
});

function UpdatePosition() {
    var posVal = $(this).val();
    var idArr = $(this).attr("id");
```

Now I would like to change it so that I can use the Update function for other fields. So far I have changed it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='pos_']").change(function () { update('Position'); })
});

function update(fld) {

    var val = $(this).val();
    var idArr = $(this).attr("id");
    var propertyName = fld;
```

But now I have a problem as before the function used the $(this).  Now when I have my general purpose
function then the $(this) no longer works.  How can I pass a reference to the thing that changed as a 
parameter to the update function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vivin's solution, or you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[id^='pos_']").change(function () { update($(this), 'Position'); })
});

function update(fieldThatChanged, fld) {

var val = fieldThatChanged.val();
var idArr = fieldThatChanged.attr("id");
var propertyName = fld;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
update.apply(this, ['Position']);
```

The first argument to `apply` is the value of `this` in the execution context of the function that you are calling `apply` on.

You can also use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
update.call(this, 'Position');
```

It works the same way as `apply`, except you're not passing in the arguments to the function in an array.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[id^='pos_']").change(functin(){
         UpdatePosition($(this),property);
    });
});

function UpdatePosition(obj,prop) {
    var posVal = obj.val();
    var idArr = obj.attr("id");
```